# How To Load Data From Excel To Oracle Database Using Apex

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an `excel` file, and there is a `merge cell` on the title `column name`, how can I load that data into my `oracle` database using `APEX` without editing my `excel` file.

Thank you

Comment: APEX 18 and earlier do not include support for Excel files, you'll need to use a 3rd-party library. I list a number of options here: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2018/11/load-spreadsheet-data-into-apex/. APEX 19.1 current Statement of Direction, as well as the early adopter release, indicates they will include API support for reading XLSX files.

Comment: Thank you so much,

Answer (score 2):

If you used the Wizard and chose "Data Loading" page type, then it contains

- first row has column names (Yes / No)

option. So, if it is the first row and it has merged cells, then answer "Yes" and you'll skip that row. Otherwise, I'm not sure that you can do that without editing the input (Excel) file.

Comment: The APEX Data Loader only supports CSV files (at this time).